# OpenVPN wont connect on Fedora 30

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, openvpn

I recently switched out my work computer and changed my OS from Linux Mint to Fedora 30, since this change I have been unable to connect to my Home VPN from the computer.

I've brought my laptop in to work to verify that I am able to connect to my home vpn from another computer on the same network.

Here's a sample of the logs I'm seeing:

```
Wed May 22 11:13:12 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed May 22 11:13:12 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1b FIPS  26 Feb 2019, LZO 2.08
Enter Private Key Password: ***********
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed May 22 11:13:19 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
Wed May 22 11:14:19 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed May 22 11:14:19 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed May 22 11:14:19 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed May 22 11:14:19 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed May 22 11:14:24 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
Wed May 22 11:14:24 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed May 22 11:14:24 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed May 22 11:14:24 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
Wed May 22 11:15:25 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed May 22 11:15:25 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed May 22 11:15:25 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed May 22 11:15:25 2019 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed May 22 11:15:30 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
Wed May 22 11:15:30 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed May 22 11:15:30 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed May 22 11:15:30 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]my-ip:1194
```

Please let me know if any other details are required and I'll be happy to supply them, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I'm an idiot that didn't notice that the ovpn profile generated for my work computer had the incorrect IP address for my home network. I'm not sure why or how a newly generated profile (generated by pivpn) would not have had the correct IP but once I had changed the IP in the work profile to match that in the laptop profile it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the Internet?

> Wed May 22 11:14:19 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)

Comment: Hi there, I'm definitely connected to the internet as I'm currently using the same computer two post and comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You normally find that timeouts are indicative of some sort packets being dropped by a firewall somewhere.

I would have thought that this would be on the server end, however if you are saying this works from another device then I guess it's your client.

It may be worth retesting when allowing all traffic.

Run the following to do so:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Then retest this your VPN connection.

It's a really bad idea to leave these rules in place so run the following after:

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT 1
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT 1
```

Alternatively, reboot your PC to reset the iptables rules.

You could also test this with ncat.

Run

```
sudo yum install nc
```

Then run

```
nc {YOUR HOME IP} 1194
```

Have you checked the logs from the successful connection on your laptop to ensure that you are using the same port?